# Can anyone who had food at annual pithru/bhathru ritual cermony function visit other person's house?

Tags: rituals, dharma-shastras

Can anyone who attend an annual pithru/bhathru ceremony function and after having food in ceremony can directly go or visit some other closer relative's house?

What Dharma Shastra say about this?

Answer (score 3):

> Manu Smriti 3.249. The foolish man who, after having eaten a Sraddha
>   (-dinner), gives the leavings to a Sudra, falls headlong into the
>   Kalasutra hell.
>
> Manu Smriti 3.250. If the partaker of a Sraddha (-dinner) enters on
>   the same day the bed of a Sudra female, the manes of his (ancestors)
>   will lie during that month in her ordure

AFAIK, these are the only two restrictions for a person who took a Shraddha meal. No such restrictions, like what you have mentioned, are there .